# First error: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: apex, lightning, rest-api, controller, json

Below is my batch class which gets data from external systeglobal class LogClass implements

```
Database.Batchable<Integer>,Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {
 global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
       Integer[] values = new Integer[0];
while(values.size() < 2999) {
    values.add(values.size());
}
return Test.isRunningTest() ? new Integer[1] : values ;
}
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Integer[] values) {
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setEndpoint('<endpoint>');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + <token>);
        Http policyhttp = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = policyhttp.send(req);
        String response = res.getBody();
        JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(response, JsonParser.class);  
        
        JsonParser.cls_value clsValue = objJsonParser.value;
        Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data> dataMap = new Map<String, JsonParser.cls_data>();
        for(JsonParser.cls_data data: clsValue.data){
            dataMap.put(data.id, data);
        }
        list<log__c> updatelist = new list<log__c>();
        for (String getId : dataMap.keySet()){
            
            log__c log = new log__c(
                log_id__c = dataMap.get(getId).id,
                log_name__c = dataMap.get(getId).agentId);
            updatelist.add(log);  
        }
        try{
            upsert updatelist log_id__c;    
        }
        catch(DmlException e){
            system.debug('This class didnt compile');
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        
    }
}
```

Below is my JSON Parser Class:

```
public class JSONParser{
    public Integer code;    
    public cls_value value;
    public class cls_value {
        public cls_data[] data;
        public String message;  
        public Integer code;    
    }
    public class cls_data {
        public String logID;    
        public string logName;  
    }
    
    
    public static JSONParser parse(String json){
        return (JSONParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSONParser.class);
    }

    
}
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "value": {
        "data": [
            {
                "logId": "0001102",
                "logName": "testlog"
            }
        ],
        "message": "Data retrieved successfully.",
        "code": 10334
    }
}
```

Now, when I run the batch class, although the records are getting processed, but I am seeing the error as

> First error: No content to map to Object due to end of input

In the debug log, I found that this error is around this line

```
JsonParser objJsonParser = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(response, JsonParser.class);
```

I'm wondering what went wrong here as the records are getting updated in one batch but other batches are failing with this error. Can anyone please suggest changes to my code so that I can get this done.

Comment: This error generally comes when the response is either blank `''` or an empty space `' '`. There might be few scenarios in which your response is blank or empty space. It will never come with the response you have given.